# Ajax loading and previous active scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I call a loading function for loading content into my `#content` div.
All work but my problem is this div contains sometimes content that needs a script to run.
(here MIXITUP)

For now, I call ( callback function ) the function who runs mixitup after loading (ajax) but when I load content more than one time, mixitup seems to be a little lost, the filters btn lost active class.

Here's my code for my file AJAX.php:

```
$(function() {
    // historique
    $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
        console.log( "popstate event" );

        var url = window.location;
        var hash = url.href.substring(url.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

        $('#content').load( url + ' #content');
    });

    // hide loading
    $('#loading').hide();

    // menu action link click
    $('.menu a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#loading').slideDown(500);

        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#loading').offset().top }, 20);

        $('.menu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');

        var lien = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#content').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('#content').load( lien + ' #content> *', function () {    
                $('#content').fadeIn(500, function() {
                    $('#loading').slideUp();

                    history.pushState(null, null, lien);
                });
            }); 
        });
    });
});
```

And here is my.js

```
function mixitNow() {
    $('.mixit').mixItUp({
        load: {
            filter: 'all' 
        },
        controls: {
            toggleFilterButtons: false,
            toggleLogic: 'or',
            live: true,
        },
        callbacks: {
            onMixEnd: function(state) {
                $("body").getNiceScroll().resize();
            }
        }
    });

    $( "a.toggle" ).click(function() {
        $(".linkto a.toggle[data-target="+$(this).attr('data-target')+"]").toggleClass( "active" );
        // Trigger the NiceScroll to resize
        $("body").getNiceScroll().resize();
    });

    $('.navmenu').niceScroll({cursorcolor: "#84dbff", cursorborder: "none", cursorwidth: "4px", cursorborderradius: "0", scrollspeed: "100"});
    $("body").niceScroll({cursorcolor: "#22ABDE", cursorborder: "1px solid #fff", cursorborderradius: "0", scrollspeed: "100"});
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    mixitNow(); //works
    console.log( "doc ready call 2 mixit" );
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
    console.log( "ajaxSuccess" );
    mixitNow(); //works
});
```

Comment: So i need to find a way to always check my content and run the script if needed OR rune JUST ONCE the function after content loading

Comment: use .find to target .mixit and pass it into the MixitNow function will be a good idea or not ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found a solution to this? thank you

Answer (score 0):

instead of .load() you could use $.ajax and make use of the success handler

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success:function(response){
        // check response and 
        if(xyz){
            mixItUp()
        }else {
            // else no mixin
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried but loading doesn't work

        $('#content').ajax({
    url: url, or $url
    type: 'GET',
    success:function(response){
        // check response and 
        if(xyz){
            mixItUp()
        }else {
            // else no mixin
        }
    }

})

Comment: If i use this, it's the same problem, when I click on the link, the function seems to be running twice.
On click works but after another reload Mixit up is lost

Comment: Ok so I tried to

-load mixitUp, after ajax load.

load from callback
use $.ajax

but it's the same problem, when I click on the link, the function seems to be running twice. On click works but after another reload Mixit up is lost

Answer (score 0):

You must delete the instance of MixItUp from the memory before your new ajax call, otherwise further instantiations on the same element will be blocked. Call this before making the ajax call.

```
try {
        $('.mixit').mixItUp('destroy');
    }catch(x) {}
```